# Odoo 10 POS Android Webview not showing properly

Tags: html, css, odoo

I have created a Webview of my POS but it shows like below:

[image: Click to See the Image]

How can I make that responsive?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
mWebView.setInitialScale(1);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
mWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>

<div class="w3-container">
  <h2>The w3-mobile Class</h2>
  <p>The <strong>w3-mobile</strong> class adds mobile-first responsivenss to any element.</p>
  <p>It adds display:block and width:100% to an element on screens that are less than 600px wide.</p>

  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect:</p>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-mobile">Home</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-mobile">Link 1</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-mobile">Link 2</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-mobile">Link 3</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

this code maybe solve your problem